# How do I represent an Object Array in XML with data binding?

Tags: android-databinding

With data binding, I am trying to connect my member variable `Tile[] tiles` which resides in `Model model` to the `TextView`s in my XML file. However, I am getting the following gradle error:

```
Error:(106, 33) Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. tiles is missing it
```

This is (part of) my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="(Tile[]) tiles"
            type="com.myapp.Model" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv0"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text='@{tiles[0].getValue == 0 ? "" : tiles[0].getValue}'
                android:textSize='@{tiles[0].getValue &lt; 100 ? "48sp" : tiles[0].getValue &lt; 1000 ? "36sp" : "24sp"}'/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text='@{tiles[1].getValue == 0 ? "" : tiles[1].getValue}'
                android:textSize='@{tiles[1].getValue &lt; 100 ? "48sp" : tiles[1].getValue &lt; 1000 ? "36sp" : "24sp"}'/>

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

This is (part of) my `Model` class:

```
class Model {
    private Tile[] tiles = new Tile[16];

    Model(Tile[] tiles) {
        setTiles(tiles);
    }

    Tile[] getTiles(){ return tiles;}

    void setTiles(Tile[] tiles) { System.arraycopy(tiles, 0, this.tiles, 0, tiles.length); }

    int getValue(int index) { return tiles[index].getValue(); }

    void setValue(int index, int value) { tiles[index].setValue(value); }

    int getId(int index) { return tiles[index].getId(); }

    void setId(int index, int id) { tiles[index].setId(id);}
}
```

And this is (part of) my `Tile` class:

```
class Tile {
    private int value;
    private int id;

    Tile(int id, int value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }

    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Most likely, this line is wrong: `type="com.myapp.Model"`, since the type of my tiles variable is not `Model`, but the compiler/gradle does not let me put `com.myapp.Tile` nor `com.myapp.Tile[]` nor `com.myapp.Model.Tile[]`. How do I correctly declare my `Tile[]` variable?

Comment: Before someone asks: dataBinding is enabled in gradle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this in your xml :

```
<variable
    name="tiles"
    type="com.<your package>.Tile[]"/> //it might show you an error in xml but you can ignore it.
```

and set its value from activity/fragment/viewmodel

```
binding.setTiles(<your array>);
```

Make sure your `Tile` class and its variable are public.

```
public class Tile {
    public int value;
    public int id;
    .
    .
    .
}
```